# System 76 Oryx Pro with Samsung 4k flickering issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, hdmi, 4k-monitor

I got my Oryx Pro hooked up to my Samsung U28D590D. Using various connections I get the following behaviour:

Displayport:

- random artifac happening across the screen (similar to artifacts)
- random flickering where the screen goes black and then returns to normal

HDMI:

- random flickering where the screen goes black and then returns to normal.

I currently have the 352.63 drivers installed. I have tried using the compiz setting on workaround to force a full screen refresh and also tried disabling dithering as recommended in some related questions, but nothing has worked so far. The HDMI connection works 100% on another system also running Ubuntu.

Comment: When I got more oryx and started using it with my 4k monitor I had to set my refresh rate to auto inside the nvidia server settings.  I do still have the issue where the screen will randomly sleep and wake up but it only happens once or twice a day and isn't a huge deal for me. Pretty sure this is due to to the monitor auto detection as well. I have a Dell monitor though so maybe it is ubuntu/oryx

Answer (score 0):

The system76 Oryx Pro notebook ships with the relatively new NVIDIA GTX 9M series.
Generally it is recommended to use the NVIDIA drivers from the Ubuntu repositories.
When you have issues, you can alternatively use the drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA.

So you should try to repair the drivers installation first.

**Step 1 : Remove the installed NVIDIA 352 drivers.**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2 : Re-install the NVIDIA 352 drivers.**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case everything works, you are done.
If not, perform the alternative solution.

**Step 1 : Remove the installed NVIDIA 352 drivers.**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2 : Install the latest NVIDIA 361 drivers.**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Sadly, none of these have resolved anything. Under any circumstances I would've suspected a hardware fault, but the HDMI cable and the screen works fine @ 4k with my desktop.

Comment: @HannesBenson : These solutions should have worked, they did in many similar cases ... maybe you have to adjust some graphics settings in BIOS ?

Comment: I have a feeling that mine might not be gfx driver related and might have to do with the screen auto detection. Having watched the screen for a while it goes blank completely and comes back on after a second or 2. Using the displayport cable I have it'll even revert any set resolution back to 3840x2160. I'm still looking into how I can force Ubuntu to stop doing that, but it seems I'm gonna need a lot of trial and error with a xorg.conf file.